# Query does not return results in wordpress, but running manually does

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have the following code in WordPress

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
$testQuery = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name 
                             WHERE service_id = %d 
                             AND   token = %s" , $service_id, $token);
$testResult = $wpdb->get_results($testQuery,ARRAY_A);

echo "<pre>testQuery\n$testQuery\n";
echo "testResult: "; print_r($testResult);
echo "db error:" . $wpdb->last_error;
echo "</pre>";
```

When I copy-paste the result printed in my echo to phpmyadmin and run the query, it shows results, however, when running the query within wordpress, my $testResult is an empty array.   $wpdb->last_error does not print any error message.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `echo "db error: . $wpdb->last_error;` has a missing quote  if that is your actual code. So change it to `echo "db error: " .  $wpdb->last_error;` see if that pops up an error.

Comment: This is not the actual code I must say, I put something together that should display the message. 
I've tried echo $wpdb->last_error and $wpdb->show_errors(); $wpdb->print_error(); but no error message to be seen.